# How to get Multiple values using Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to fetch 1st category data in category div and subcategory data in sub-cat div.
i am using Ajax , Jquery. i have tried below code but result shows undefined. Please let me know where the code is wrong ?

HTML is :

```
<body class="bg-color">
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div class="border-radius">
            <div class="box-heading">Assignment</div>
                <div class="footer group">
                    <div id="category">
                    5
                    </div>
                    <div id="sub-cat">
                        5                 
                    </div>
                    <div id="sub-cat1">
                    5                  
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                    
                 });
function pageLoad()
{
    var result = new Array();
    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "get.php",
                        data: "",
                        async: false
    }).responseText.split(",");
document.getElementById('category').innerHTML = result[0];  

}
window.onload = pageLoad;


</script>
```

PHP code is

```
<?php
    require("_assets/config/dbc.php");


        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");

        while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $a = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="vote1(' . $row['cat_id'] . ');">' .$row['title'] . '</a></p>';
        }
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory");
        while($row1  = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
        $b = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="vote1(' . $row1['cat_id'] . ');">' .$row1['title'] . '</a></p>';
        }

        echo $result = $a."*".$b;

?>
```

Actually i want when the page is load ajax go to get.php file and get category by ID , sub category by id and sub sub category by ID. so i will show these on my 3 divs.. Please sort out my this problem..

Comment: what is result array? where u loading it from?

Comment: result array is showing undefined. i am loading on index.php main form.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this  by json  in php use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ( Returns the JSON representation of a value) to encode value and in ajax try

for example in php

```
$sequential = array("foo", "bar", "baz", "blong");
echo  json_encode($sequential);
```

and in ajax success try

```
success: function(data) {
       data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by itself. my code is :

```
function vote(id)
{ 
    var result = new Array();
     result = $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "ajax.php",
                       data: "work=vote&id="+id,
                       async: false
               }).responseText.split("^");
document.getElementById('sub-cat').innerHTML = result[0];
document.getElementById('sub-cat1').innerHTML = result[1];
//window.location.reload()
}
```

now i am facing another problem.. please let me know how to get 1st value of while loop. so i will get sub sub category using sub category id..

php code is :

```
<?php
    require("_assets/config/dbc.php");

    if($_REQUEST['work']=="vote")
    {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE cat_id='$id'");
    $HTML= "";
        while($result  = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $HTML .= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="vote1(' . $result['subcat_id'] . ');">' .$result['title'] . '</a></p>';  
        }
    $HTML .= "^";
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from subscategory "HOW TO GET 1ST SUBCATEGORY ID?"") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $HTML .= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="vote1(' . $row['subcat_id'] . ');">' .$row['title'] . '</a></p>';


        }

    echo $HTML;
    }

?>
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql ...bad guy will kill your website

Comment: buddy this just a sample test. its not a working website.. :)